# PHP: Special chars not shown correctly

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a value (name) stored in pg database, the value is `Müller`. However, for example when I `var_dump('Müller');` I get output : `MÃ1/4ller`.

I've tried setting `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` and no go.

Funny thing is, I'm not getting this issue on client side, name is displaying correctly, but on server end, when breaking up the first three letters of the name instead of getting:

```
array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "M"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "ü"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "l"
}
```

I get:

```
array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "M"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "Ã"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "1/4"
}
```

I figure that since the database is storing the value correctly, that must be a php thing, but haven't been able to figure it out after quite a bit of googling, so maybe I am not searching for the correct query?

Comment: When you are var_dumping are you var_dumping the static `Müller` or the db value `$row['column']`? It sounds like your DB isn't in UTF8.

Comment: @chris85 I tried both.

Comment: string(1) "1/4"  Really?  Are you sure you haven't modified your copy and paste? Or are you really getting 3 characters there?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Yes, sorry, that was modified, 1/4 was one character (so two in total including the A with the tilde above it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your schema configuration.

Try `utf8_decode()` before dumping with PHP.
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php

Alternatively you can use `utf8_encode()`, to encode a string back to utf8